# como puedo llamar dos archivos js distintos en mi html

Tags: javascript, html

Actualmente estoy desarrollando mi primera pagina web, y esta trata sobre el juego de la vida de conway, mi intención es al principio de la pagina poner una pequeña "demo" en la que solo se pueda ver correr el juego, y despues un juego en el que se pueda interactuar.
para esto dispuse dos archivos js distintos, el primero ya lo pude incluir con éxito, pero no he podido hacer que el segundo aparezca.

```
<body onload="inicia();">
    <main>
    <article style="flex: 75%;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #f3f3f3; margin: 0px; height: 700px;">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; padding-top: 40px;" >El juego de la vida</h1>
        <script src="js/demojdv.js"></script>
        <div style="text-align: center; padding-top: 3%;">
            <canvas id="demo" style="border: 0px;"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

así llame al primer archivo.

de antemano, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Una pregunta, pero de que forma quieres cargarlos?, una sintaxis en particular?, con etiquetas script?, de que en forma en particular?, porque apartir de `ES6` ya hay otras formas, pero no veo que menciones en ningun momento en la pregunta que quieras usar funcionalidades de `ES6` para incluir scripts,  si tu pregunta era mas concreta acerca de una sintaxis en especifico que no te funciona entonces deberas agregarla, de lo contrario no sabremos realmente al final lo que deseas.

Comment: Hola Samuel, las respuestas que dejaron son muy utiles. Solo queria recordarte que si tienes una funcion que necesita de otra para su ejecucion o alguna funcionalidad que quieras que se ejecute primero antes que otra debes recordar el orden de tus archivos, por ejemplo, bootstrap requiere jquery para algunas funciones, por ende, si no esta cargado previamente estas funciones no se podran ejecutar.

Comment: @RobertoVargas cierto, esa informacion tambien es de mucha utilidad, se me olvido mencionarlo en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya ha comentado el usuario de arriba lo más conveniente es que coloques las etiquetas  antes de la etiqueta de cierre .

En cuanto a llamar archivos .js puedes llamar cuantos quieras, claro siguiendo el primer punto.

```
<script src="js/demojdv.js"></script>
<script src="js/demojdv2.js"></script>
<script src="js/demojdv3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Las etiquetas `script` por conveniencia y estandar normalmente son puestas al final de la etiqueta `<head>` de `html` siendo que lo primero que deberia cargarse son los estilos, luego le siguen los `scripts` y luego la pagina entera:

```
<head>
   ...
   <script src="js/demojdv.js"></script>
</head>
```

Por lo tanto considera que meter una etiqueta `script` dentro de un `div` **es valido** pero no conveniente.

La idea es tener un apartado (en este caso el head), el cual es donde van a ir todas las cargas de `scripts` que necesites.

Dicho eso, la forma en la que puedes cargar mas de un `script` en una pagina, es simplemente agregando otra etiqueta `script` hacia ese archivo:

```
<head>
   ...
   <script src="js/demojdv.js"></script>
   <script src="otroArchivo.js">
</head>
```

Pero para solventar cualquier incoveniente que pudieras tener a futuro, es que si haces esto deberas tener en cuenta el orden en el que se cargan las cosas:

- estilos
- scripts
- cuerpo de la pagina
- pagina (todo lo anterior)

Si bien es bastante normal esa forma de cargar las cosas, lo conveniente para que no surjan problemas en tu script es cargar los recursos de esta forma:

- estilos
- cuerpo de la pagina
- scripts
- pagina (todo lo anterior)

De esta manera primero se cargara el cuerpo de tu pagina y luego los `scripts`, esto es conveniente para cuando nosotros usamos `javascript` en atributos `html`, como lo haces en tu codigo:

```
<body onload="inicia();">
```

vemos que intentas llamar a una funcion `inicia()` cuando la pagina se cargue, pero el problema de esto es que esa funcion para poder reconocerse y ser ejecutada **debe haberse cargado previamente**.

Por esa razon digo que es conveniente cargar las cosas de la segunda manera.

Para la carga de informacion hay otra forma que se considera estandar que resuelve muchos problemas, y es que, en vez de colocar tus etiquetas `<script>` al final del `<head>`, muchas personas lo que hacen es colocar sus scripts al final del `body`, de esta manera se cargara primero el cuerpo de la pagina y luego los `scripts` para que no haya ningún conflicto en ellos:

```
<body>
   ...
   ...
    <script src="js/demojdv.js"></script>
    <script src = "script2.js"></script>
</body>
```

Sin embargo haciendolo de esa manera seguira teniendo el mismo problema, y es que tu funcion llamada `inicia();` no va a ejecutarse debido a que el `html` esta intentando organizar su carga para enlazar una función **inicia** que aun no ha sido cargada (aun no existe en la pagina).

Una solucion sencilla es en vez de usar una `funcion` llamada **inicia** para que se ejecute tu `script` es directamente llamar a las utilidades de la ventana, para que puedas ejecutar tu codigo de manera directa, por lo tanto primero que todo deberas quitar el evento que tienes del `body`:

```
<body>
...
...
</body>
```

Lo segundo sera decirle al script (`js/demojdv.js`), que ejecute el codigo cuando la pagina se cargue por completo, por lo cual deberas colocar en ella y encerrar todo tu codigo dentro de:

```
//Apartado A

window.onload = ()=>{
   //Aqui dentro TODO tu codigo
}
```

donde `window.onload` se encarga de esperar a que se cargue todo en la ventana para que posteriormente se ejecute todo el codigo que se encuentra ahi dentro.

No te preocupes por eventos ni nada de eso, todo seguira funcionando normal si ejecutas tu codigo dentro del cuerpo de `window.onload` anteriormente mencionado.

Ahora bien, veras que en el anterior codigo hice mencion a un `Apartado A` ese apartado es donde se supone deberas colocar funciones que quieres que esten relacionadas directamente en el HTML antes de que la pagina se cargue, por lo tanto:

- Si vas a añadir eventos desde el `HTML` para usar funciones de un `script`, tus `scripts` **deberian** ir en el `<head>` y ademas las funciones que se invoquen por medio de eventos en el `HTML` deben ir por fuera de `window.onload`.
- Aquellos eventos o funciones que no esten siendo usadas directamente en el HTML si no que se usan solo dentro del `JS` pueden y deberian ir dentro de `window.onload`.

Por ultimo una recomendacion:

Si vas a manejar eventos definidos desde el `HTML` entonces **NO** uses `window.onload` simplemente **pon tus scripts al final del body** de lo contario deberas usar `window.onload` y agregar las funciones que relaciones directamente en el `HTML` por fuera de `window.onload`.

De lo contrario pon todo en `window.onload` y **NO** definas eventos desde el **HTML**, para asi poder manejar todo desde `window.onload` y no tener que dejar funciones por fuera de `window.onload` para que funcionen, **recuerda que tambien puedes añadirle eventos a tus elementos directamente desde JS sin tocar el HTML**.